# Find 0, 1, or possibly 2 matches within a single JOIN statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, multiple-columns

Is there a simple way to find potentially two different matches from the same table row in a JOIN statement?  For example, I have a storage table called st that looks like this:

```
Unique ID    Log_ID1    [other fields]    Log_ID2
1            25         ...               30
```

There is a log table called lt that is written to when the Log_IDx fields get filled in and it looks like this:

```
Log_ID    SomeDetail
1         ...
...       ...
25        I need this part if Log_ID1 is not null
...       ...
30        I also need to get this part if Log_ID2 is not null
```

The table st will get initialized with some data and then, as necessary, the row will be updated with the Log_ID1 and Log_ID2 data.  I need to get to the log data if either one exists, or if both exist, I need to get to both rows.  I've tried this and it doesn't work:

```
SELECT [fieldList]
FROM   lt a
INNER JOIN st b ON a.Log_ID = b.Log_ID1
INNER JOIN st c ON a.Log_ID = c.Log_ID2
```

If I remove either INNER JOIN, it works, but it doesn't return all the data (obviously) if both Log_ID1 and Log_ID2 are populated.  For that reason, this also doesn't work:

```
SELECT [fieldList]
FROM   lt a
INNER JOIN (st b ON a.Log_ID = b.Log_ID1) [AND][OR]
(st c ON a.Log_ID = b.Log_ID2)
```

It's possible to have NULLs in both Log_ID fields, in either one, or to have both of them contain data.

Is there a simple/elegant construct that can pull 0, 1 or 2 rows of data depending on the state of the storage table?  Or will I have to write some ugly code to get what I'm after?  Maybe a union of some sort?

Syntactically speaking, since it may be easier to understand, I'm looking for something that would do this, but be legal syntax:

```
SELECT [fieldList]
FROM   lt a
INNER JOIN st b ON a.Log_ID IN (b.Log_ID1, b.Log_ID2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly this, depend on the content of your data UNION ALL will keep all data, UNION will remove duplicate

```
SELECT [fieldList]
FROM   lt a
INNER JOIN st b ON a.Log_ID = b.Log_ID1

UNION ALL

SELECT [fieldList]
FROM   lt a
INNER JOIN st b ON a.Log_ID = b.Log_ID2
```

Comment: This one worked.  The one below only returned the first set of data if both Log_ID1 and Log_ID2 have values.

Answer (score 0):

You want a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.  And then you include a WHERE clause to filter out rows where both results are NULL.

Something like this:

```
SELECT [fieldList]
  FROM lt a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN st b ON a.Log_ID = b.Log_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN st c ON a.Log_ID = c.Log_ID
 WHERE NOT (b.Log_ID IS NULL AND c.Log_ID IS NULL)
```

Comment: Depending on what you want you can alter this ... for example, remove the NOT and change the AND to OR if that's what you want.  But there's no reason this shouldn't work for you.

Comment: I altered it a few different ways.  My query was more complex than I let on.  I only shared what I thought was pertinent.  There were other existing parts in my where clause which may have been altering the outcome as well.  I appreciate your input but I found that the UNION ALL did exactly what I need, and since I'm not dealing with millions of rows here, the performance isn't a concern either.

Comment: Understood. The UNION ALL shouldn't be a performance problem as long as you don't have an ORDER BY at the bottom (which will inject a sort). UNION ALL doesn't do distinct sorting or de-duplication, so it's pretty fast and efficient.